# Plotting trees on sagemath

Tags: graph-theory, trees, sagemath

I'm an undergraduate student doing an independent research on trees, and I want to generate trees and plot them. I'm using a sage notebook with the ipynb extension (using my university's remote computer). The following code, which I copied from the [sage website](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_plot.html) is not plotting trees as expected (I originally had my own code with which I was trying to plot, but since it wasn't working I tried to copy some examples from this link). \

```
from sage.all import *
T = list(graphs.trees(7))
t = T[3]
t.graphplot().plot()
```

Instead of showing the graphs, it returns `"Graphics object consisting of 14 graphics primitives."`
I can use other sage functions on the same platform, so I was wondering if anyone have any experience troubleshooting such an error.

Comment: What happens if you add `t.graphplot(layout='tree').show()`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs It still says "Graphics object consisting of 14 graphics primitives" and doesn't return any actual graphics :(